# How do I jenkins permission on a per job basis?

Tags: jenkins

Some jobs push to QA and some jobs push to Production.

Only devs should be allowed to push to QA and only QA should be allowed to push to production. Aside from making two separate build servers (with some way to share artifacts) how do I restrict permissions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy** in Global Configuration, and on the Job Configuration, use **Enable Project-based Security**.

<strike>[**It's all explained here**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/2012/01/03/Allow+access+to+specific+projects+for+Users(Assigning+security+for+projects+in+Jenkins))</strike>
[**Standard Security Explained**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup)

Comment: The link is now broken. Is Gareth's link now the relevant one?

Comment: @TomislavNakic-Alfirevic Gareth's link explains the individual permissions of matrix-based security. My link explains how to setup matrix-based security. I've added a new link, since the original appears to have moved. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You have to manage restrictions with the tools that Jenkins provides. 
If you have administrator status go to "Jenkins configuration" (picture 1) and then to "Manage and assign roles" (picture 2). Here you will see "Manage roles" and "Assign roles".

[image: Access to jenkins configuration from dashboard]
[image: Jenkins manage and assign roles]
[image]

Use "Manage roles" to create/update roles and assign permissions to determined projects and also to manage the restrictions of each job.
Use "Manage and Assign roles" to assign roles to users or to other groups.

Role/permission matrix:

[image: Permission matrix for Jenkins]

Thus you can configure groups to administrate determined jobs, to execute other jobs or to simply have the ability to visit and see job details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [matrix-based security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) to achieve this.

Comment: In the document you sent, it lists build as permission to "Start a new build." I may be blind, but where is the start a new build permission for individual jobs? edit: Ah, so this is a feature of project based matrix security, then?

Comment: Yes, project based matrix security lets you assign the "start new build" permission for individual jobs.  Job and project are synonyms in Jenkins.

Comment: Using the OP's example, assume there is a `DeployToQA` job and a `DeployToProd` job, where developers should not be able to execute the `DeployToProd` job.  Can you make that happen using matrix-based security?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the user account is created
2. Do not add that user to the global configuration security but do have project matrix enabled security enabled and authenticated users read access
3. Now go to the job and add that user and choose read.
4. You can now see that the user has only access to that specific job

Answer (score 0):

I just found the [ownership based security](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ownership-plugin/blob/master/doc/OwnershipBasedSecurity.md) method for doing per-job and per-node permissions. Not applicable in all situations but sometimes very useful - like when other teams are running few jobs on your team's instance.