# Restrict access to jenkins user

Tags: jenkins, user-permissions, role-based-access-control

We are using Jenkins Role based strategy to give permissions. My QA is given permission build and cancel jobs at global roles. I have created project role with matching pattern to give him access to deploy on QA environment. But Because of global roles he is able to build deploy on prod job. How to stop him accessing Prod job and make him access only the QA job.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with role based authentication, the Role Strategy Plugin page specifically says that global roles override per project roles. If this behavior is a hard requirement you will probably need to look at other authentication schemes perhaps this question (which is asking about how to solve the same problem you are asking about) could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577254/how-do-i-jenkins-permission-on-a-per-job-basis

Answer (score 0):

**Remove all global roles**.

Provide permissions individually to prod and QA jobs by **using separate project role patterns**.